# Apache Airflow dags list shows no dags

Tags: airflow, command-line-interface, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've got a problem with Apache Airflow within the cli.
The command `airflow dags list` show no dags.
Also "airflow task test dagid task01 2020-01-01" does not run my dags.

In the gui how-ever everything runs as expected. I see al my dags en they run as they should run.

When i do an 'airflow users list' everything seems okay on the CLI. I see my username(s). When I change this user in de web gui it also changes in here (CLI). So the used DB must be the same.

I'm using docker with Airflow version 2.5.3. I update from an older version where the same problem occured out of nothing. (That's why I updated Airflow)

Anybody some clues?

I tried updating Airflow. Checked all the permissions.
Also checked all paths en env variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your docker setup for Airflow is, specifically whether dags/logs have been volume mounted?

Did you do "airflow db upgrade" as well? We had somewhat similar issue but after running following commands, it was ok.

```
airflow db reset -y
airflow db init
```

Comment: I reinstalled docker with this instructions: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html

Comment: I tried reset and init. That unfortunately cleared out my variables and connections in my database. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Dags and logs are indeed volume mounted

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was within a specific DAG. For now I don't know exactly what the problem with this dag is, but when I deleted it from the directory everything worked again. The webinterface however didn't show any errors regarding this specific dag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue. I'm using Managed Apache airflow in AWS. I'm trying to activate a dag using AWS lambda and I'm trying to list the dags and check if the dag I want to run is paused or not using the `airflow dags list` command.

However, the dag list command only lists some dags and some dags are missing. I have investigated the issue and found out that when a dag imports SSHOperator then that dag is no longer listing for the airflow cli command. But dag shows without any issues in the Airflow UI and can be triggered in the UI and from the Airflow cli command. `airflow dags trigger`.

```
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
```

When I removed the SSHOperator import, the dag lists without any issue. I investigated for a couple of days but couldn't find a solution. So I used the following workaround.

Used `dags unpause <dag_id>` to unpause the dag regardless if a dag is paused or unpaused.

Use `dags list-runs -o json` to list the dags, and filter out the dag I want, but dag must have at least one run to list the dag here.

```
filtered_json = [dag_run for dag_run in output_json if dag_run['dag_id'] == dag_id]
```

Hope this helps.